# C# Button is a field, but used like a type

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I'm trying to make a tic-tac-toe program in C#, but when I was setting up the event handler for clicking the button, I got the error ""button1 is a field, but used as a type" I don't know why this is happening, considering that the program so far is almost identical to the start of my first project in C#, which worked fine.

```
namespace Project_2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, System.EventArgs e);
        public class Button
        {
            private EventHandler handler;

            public event EventHandler Click
            {
                add { handler += value; }
                remove { handler -= value; }
            }

        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(button1_Click);
            button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(button2_Click);
            button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(button3_Click);
            button4.Click += new System.EventHandler(button4_Click);
            button5.Click += new System.EventHandler(button5_Click);
            button6.Click += new System.EventHandler(button6_Click);
            button7.Click += new System.EventHandler(button7_Click);
            button8.Click += new System.EventHandler(button8_Click);
            button9.Click += new System.EventHandler(button9_Click);

        }
        void button1.Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }

}
```

Any and all help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Your handler method should be named `button1_Click`, not `button1.Click` (underscore, not period).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the very least you can't have a `.` in a method name. So your click handler should be:

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Try that out!

Comment: Thank you! I kind of feel stupid now.

Answer (score 0):

```
button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(button1_Click);
```

Is valid! Because using this, you would set the Click event handler for the `button1`. But

```
void button1.Click() { }
```

Is *invalid* and is causing the trouble. This is like you're trying to invoke the method `Click` on the button1.

Try naming it using some other name. Like `button1Click` or `button1_Click`. Also, you should always remember the naming convention of C# Identifiers. They're not allowed to have any special character other than `_`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // add code here
}
```